# Override WebClientProtocol.Timeout via web.config

Tags: .net, configuration

Is it possible to override default value of [WebClientProtocol.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.timeout.aspx) property via web.config?

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="500" /> <!-- this doesn't help -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant think of a way to have just the Timeout property changed automatically via the webconfig.

Manually configure the value or use DI to read the value in for you.

It maybe possible also to change the value globally on the machine config.